# Plotting the occurrences of certain words in every book chapter

Tags: python, matplotlib, count, nlp, nltk

I have 5 text files, each corresponding to a book chapter (they are actually very short). I want to see how often various characters are mentioned.

This is how the contents are read (for every part):

```
p1 = open("p1.txt")
p1_contents = p1.read()
```

And then I do:

```
import re

def find_words(part):
  list_of_words = ["Anna", "John"]
  for word in list_of_words:
    print ("How often %s appears:" %word)
    print (len(re.findall(word, part)))

list_of_parts = [p1_contents, p2_contents, p3_contents, p4_contents, p5_contents]
for part in list_of_parts:
  find_words(part)
```

But the output looks quite ugly. Is it possible to present this output in a line graph, each line representing the occurrences of each character, throughout the parts? I know how to do this if I had a dictionary, but in my case the output is not a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is wrong with your implementation but you should only return each word's occurrence back to fill the necessary dictionary, but I change it a little to become more readable and flexible.

```
chapter1 = '''
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Et nihil adipisci a animi totam ut iusto dolorum sed eaque quod At nisi obcaecati et quae incidunt id voluptate ducimus. Qui adipisci incidunt est repellendus nihil aut suscipit odit et rerum ipsam et dolorum voluptate. 
'''
chapter2 = '''
In quos nemo et internos odio At nesciunt iure a voluptates eligendi. Ex suscipit adipisci ea sint veniam quo illo maxime. 
'''
chapter3 = '''
Quo porro totam id incidunt deserunt qui incidunt sequi. A ducimus iusto nam consequatur sunt vel amet aspernatur. In eaque alias et rerum quia est voluptas labore est deleniti mollitia aut voluptatem explicabo. Et galisum excepturi quo itaque dolorem sit impedit internos ipsum facere et laudantium corporis vel voluptatem officiis. 
'''
words = ["quos", "quod", "a"] 

Occurance = {}
for idx1, w in enumerate(words):
  temp = []
  for idx2, ch in enumerate([chapter1, chapter2, chapter3]):
    occ = ch.count(w)
    print(f"For Word Number {idx1+1}, Is Occurred {occ} times In Chapter Number {idx2+1}")
    temp.append(occ)
  print('')
  
  Occurance[w] = temp
print(Occurance)
```

plotting part:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
  

plt.plot(['ch1', 'ch2', 'ch3'], Occurance["quos"], label = "quos")
plt.plot(['ch1', 'ch2', 'ch3'], Occurance["quod"], label = "quod")
plt.plot(['ch1', 'ch2', 'ch3'], Occurance["a"], label = "a")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

output:

[image]